# Using Ruby/Rails to parse only HTML portion of incoming email (not text portion)

Tags: ruby, parsing, ruby-on-rails-4, actionmailer, email-parsing

I am writing a Ruby/Rails script that I want to parse an incoming email that is forwarded to a specific email address. I want to parse the HTML body of the email first and foremost. I have figured out out how to take the subject and the body attribute of the Mail object and convert the body attribute to a string however it includes some header text and some strange email codes/jargon (see below).  I want to parse only the main HTML body part of the email (not the plain text portion). Is there a way to only parse the HTML portion of the email?  Also, is there a way to exclude the header text & code jargon?  I am calling my email handler method from a controller action and the code for my email handler and the email body output is below:

Email Handler code

```
 class ParseEmail < ActionMailer::Base 

 def receive(email) 
   @note = Note.new
   @note.name = email.subject
   @note.body = email.body.to_s
   @note.save

   Rails.logger.debug "Number of email parts: #{email.parts.length}"
   Rails.logger.debug "Last content parts section: #{mail.parts.last.content_type.content_type}"
  end
```

Email Body after I convert it to a string:

```
--001a1143fa4c921c130523f897ec
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8

This is a test message.

-- 
Best,

Michael

--001a1143fa4c921c130523f897ec
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

This is a test message.

-- 
Best,
Michael



--001a1143fa4c921c130523f897ec--
```

Comment: It's a multipart mime message, why don't you just use a mime parser?!

Comment: Do you mean an external library or gem for mime parsing? I am trying to use the built-in ActionMailer, Ruby/Rails components. Is there a mime parser built into Ruby/Rails?

Comment: "Built in"? I doubt it, but I don't recall. But yes, I mean use an existing gem. There's zero reason to do any of this work yourself.

Comment: Any gem suggestions based on your personal experience?

Comment: Nope, I'd just search around and find one that has the functionality you need, although I tend towards gems that have recent activity.